# JavaFX Gluon Themeing Issue

Tags: css, javafx, themes, scenebuilder

[Good Themed App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKBhM.png)

[Ugly Themed App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mf2b.png)

Whenever I use Scene Builder, the window is previewed as the nice looking blue gluon theme. When I run the application, it appears with the boring theme. How do I set the theme when I start the application?

Answer (score 0):

Gluon theme isn't included in default java distribution. For using it you have to read gluon documentation and learn how to connect this module to your project.